# How was the traffic scene filmed in the movie "Deep Impact"?

Tags: production, film-techniques, deep-impact

In the film *Deep Impact* there is a scene where they show people evacuating major cities with long highways full of traffic.  How was this scene created?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### It was a new, unopened freeway, a mile long, filled with extras and their cars

The video explains a lot, but here are some interesting points:

- There were 2100 extras, in 1870 cars
- The extras brought their own clothing and props for their cars
- 116 cars were positioned every 15 minutes
- Many trucks contained food and drinks for the extras, as it was very hot that day
- Motor-homes were used by medics for anyone who felt faint
- Porta-loos were available every 1/8th of a mile
- Extras were recruited from local high-schools, and most were from Manassas
- An AM frequency was set up so that production could speak to the extras in their cars, using 1 walkie-talkie
- The entire scene was shot in 2 days
- No digital effects were used, apart from the comet

All from the following video:

---

In anticipation of the question being split in two, I haven't addressed the spaceship question.